# Verifying CoW Swap order parameters in a proposed (Gnosis) Safe transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe, cow-protocol

When using the (Gnosis) Safe to create an order on CoW Swap, how a signer can verify that the proposed transaction includes correct order parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Before signing a proposed transaction to create an order on CoW Swap, you can observe in the Safe transaction details the `orderUid`
[image: Proposed Safe transaction details]

This `orderUid` can then be copied into [CoW Protocol Explorer](https://explorer.cow.fi/) where all of the order parameters are clearly displayed